# Error handling in activiti

Tags: scala, activiti

I am trying to handle the web service exception in the workflow (activiti).Here I just created a sample process,where I am calling one of the web service through `Service Task` which throws an exception(no Sub process).
    In order to handle that exception I have added the Boundary error event and gave the error reference as "myError"(same as in code). While I'm trying to deploy ,getting an error as

```
Attribute 'attachedToRef' must appear on element 'boundaryEvent'.
```

In activiti modeler i didn't find the attribute as 'attachedToRef'.

[Here is the workflow process,which i want to deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0ARF.jpg)

Can anyone please help me out to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can handle such exception in Activiti in such way. alternatively, what you can do is create a class, call your web service via this class and enter the same in the service task.

hope it helped...

Comment: I am doing the same in my Service Task,in the class attribute of service task I'm giving the full path of my class name and inside the class calling the web service through playClient and my logic is inside try and catch block where I am able to get an exception.

Here the problem is activiti is not allowing to deploy the process itself.It is asking for attachedRef attribute.
 Can you please tell me the path of that attribute in activiti modeler

Comment: first: don't use boundary catch event with service task. it never works that way.
second: when an exception occurs you can change a process variable and on completion of the service task you can have a exclusive gateway to check if that process variable has been modified or not. and continue the process accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have a doubt,how can I forward the error to the next step of workflow process.I want to show the same error to end user.

Comment: have a user task after your service task. in your service task provide details which you want to show to the user and set the process variable. in the user task simply display the value of that variable.
note: format the variable properly as activiti won't do it for you

Answer (score 0):

You can create sub-process for error handling:

```
<process id="1" isClosed="false" isExecutable="true" processType="None">
       **main process tasks**
 <subProcess activiti:exclusive="true" id="eventSP" triggeredByEvent="true">
  <startEvent id="startError" name="StartErrorEvent">
    <errorEventDefinition id="_5"/>
  </startEvent>
  <serviceTask>
     **tasks for error**
  </serviceTask>
 </subProcess>
</process>
```

For error sub-process you've to create separate class(or smth) and execute logic for error.

Or if you want to make exception like boundary read [activiti user guide](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html?_ga=1.67385745.1079033517.1471850758#bpmnBoundaryEvent)

Answer (score 0):

This is basically because of activiti not able to figure out to which task the boundary event is attached.

To solve this try **any one** of the following:

1. Delete the boundary event and re-drag it on to the task again.
2. Try to add something like this to the xml file based on your id of the task and event.

   ```
   <boundaryEvent id="BoundaryEventId" attachedToRef="ServiceTaskId">
   ```